# Is population homogeneity applicable to binomial parameters?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, estimation, statistical-power

Are there assumptions regarding homogeneity in power calculations and significance tests when it comes to binomial parameters?

Binomial variance is estimated by np(1-p). It doesn't take any other information into account other than sample size and rate p.

In contrast, the variance in a continuous parameter is based on more information, so you can have two equal populations with same average but different variance (so sample from one population will be less reliable than the other). I assume this is why np(1-p) is called an "estimate" of binomial variance.

What if I do have more information in a binomial case? Say it's a stack of warped coins instead of visually identical coins?

It's not clear if that information is statistically important and, if so, how to incorporate it. Who knows what bunch of coins will come next from the bag of warped coins...

Any thoughts? In Frequentist thinking specifically, can the estimate of binomial variance ever be imprecise and need to be corrected in some way?

Comment: "*The variance of a binomial parameter is always the same for a given success rate e.g., rate of coin landing HEADS.*" --  Can you explain how you get this conclusion?

Comment: Binomial variance is estimated by np(1-p). I meant that for any n things with same p, the variance comes out the same. There is no way to incorporate any additional information about the things (are they homogeneous, are they all different). In contrast, with a continuous parameter, you could have n things with same average but different variance, because it's based on more information. In my example, it seems I have more information about the coins - they are warped, yet it's not clear if that information is statistically important and, if so, how to incorporate it.

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it clearer. Any thoughts? I've tried asking this questions in different ways before and no one seems to have an answer.

Comment: If you're asking about the case where the probability of a head may be different from coin to coin, so that for a given coin the distribution is binomial, but across a random sample from the population you have a mixture distribution over the binomial parameter $p$, then certainly its possible to say something about the variance of that mixture; it's related to the parameters of the distribution over $p$ in a specific way (but that resulting mixture is not called a "binomial" as your question implies). If you mean something different from what I described, ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... you'll need to carefully distinguish what you want to ask about from that.

Comment: The OP might also be interested in looking at the Poisson binomial distribution. It's the sum of binomial distributions with different success parameters.

Comment: Coins don't vary much and don't have any internal process. But if I am asking Yes/No of people, the mental process is complex, even though the average Yes rate may be 50%, like the coin. Should I expect greater variability from surveying different human beings, even if I'm sampling randomly? Is a sample of 100 perfect coins equally good as a sample of coins I can tell are all bent? Is a sample of 100 coin tosses equally good as a sample of 100 yes/no questions? Equally good = good estimate of parameter.

Comment: @Glen_b, your answer suggests creating separate distributions of each coin and then combining them into a unified distribution. I'm assuming I only get one toss of each coin, so I have no way of knowing each coins separate distribution. I only know the overall rate of the mixture from sampling all coins. What assumptions are made about coins when doing this sort of sampling? Does it assume I'm sampling the same (or nearly same) coin and only variance is due to chance?

Comment: @soakley Thanks! I see Poisson is directly related to my question. Wikipedia entry says "The ordinary binomial distribution is a special case of the Poisson binomial distribution, when all success probabilities are the same". I take this to mean that binomial significance testing and power analysis do assume I am testing identical things and estimating a single fixed parameter. If the things are different, an observed binomial distribution might be a poor approximation of the true Poisson distribution. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It's also possible that a binomial could be a good approximation to a Poisson binomial.

Comment: @soakley I tried running a simulation to see if there is a practical difference between a "fixed parameter" and a "random parameter" over the long term. For example, I tried sampling from a sack of coins that have the same p. I then sampled from a sack with an uneven ratio of 3 types of coin, each coin having a different p. Over the long term, the mean HEAD rate was designed to come out the same. However, I was expecting the mixed sack to show more variance but it didn't. Can you think of any situation where sampling from the mixed sack would produce any practical difference in the long term?